# Specifying collection elements type while instance creation

Tags: java, list, collections, arraylist, java-7

Is there any difference between the following declarations -

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

and

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

In both cases anyhow , list will have elements of type String only.

Comment: One works with Java <= 6, the other doesn't.

Comment: Just as an addition, the documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/type-inference-generic-instance-creation.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no difference. However, the first one is legal in Java <= 7 whereas the second one is legal only in Java 7 and was introduced as a short-hand notation<sup>*</sup>. The compiler will infer the generic type from the declaration.

<sup>*</sup>It was basically introduced to remove redundant information and reduce code-noise. So you now have:

```
Map<String, List<String>> myMap = new HashMap<>();
```

versus:

```
Map<String, List<String>> myMap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
```

The first one is a lot easier on the eyes.